# SQL server 2008 - populate a column for more than one record in a set

Tags: sql-server, count

```
set row pro1 pro2  Dup
1   1   AB2  AB2
1   1   AB6  AB4
1   1   AB2  NB3
2   1   AN2  QW3  
2   2   BH1  BH1
3   1   AJ1  AJ1
4   1   HU3  HU3
4   1   BH2  BH2
```

I want to populate `dup = 'Case1'` where for a given set, `pro1 = pro2` ; it is a requirement that there is more than 1 record in that set. 
Expected result:

```
set row pro1 pro2  Dup
1   1   AB2  AB2   CASE1
1   1   AB6  AB4   NULL
1   1   AB2  NB3   NULL
2   1   AN2  QW3   NULL
2   2   BH1  BH1   CASE1 
3   1   AJ1  AJ1   NULL   (even though it matches, but its just one record)
4   1   HU3  HU3   CASE1
4   1   BH2  BH2   CASE1
```

Comment: "SQL 2009"? Do you mean SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Sorry typo; SQL server 2008 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with C as
(
  select pro1,
         pro2,
         dup,
         count(*) over(partition by [set]) as setcount
  from YourTable
)
update C
set dup = 'CASE!'
where pro1 = pro2 and
      setcount > 1
```

Working sample on [SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67018)